# Using ReactJS Hooks to import exernal javascript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to insert an external support Javascript file (extension file for bootstrap-table to maintain fixed column functionality). The way in which I am doing this is by implementing useEffects in React Hooks:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const ImportJSScript = (resourceUrl) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = resourceUrl;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [resourceUrl]);
};
export default ImportJSScript;
```

Then in the component we include:

```
import React from 'react';
import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Aux';

import ImportJSScript from '../../../../hooks/ImportJSScript';

const Table = () => {

    const importedscript = ImportJSScript('../../../../assets/js/bootstrap-table/fixed-columns/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.js');

    const style = {
        width:'100%'
      };

    return (
        <Aux>
            {importedscript}
            <div id="toolbar">

            </div>
        <table style={style}
            id="table"
            data-classes="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-sm"
            data-show-toggle="false"
            data-buttons-class="primary"
            data-show-fullscreen="false"
            data-show-columns="false"
            data-show-columns-toggle-all="false"
            data-detail-view="false"
            data-show-export="false"
            data-click-to-select="true"
            data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
            data-minimum-count-columns="2"
            data-show-pagination-switch="false"
            data-pagination="false"
            data-id-field="id"
            data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
            data-show-footer="false"
            data-response-handler="responseHandler"
            data-sticky-header="true">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="site" data-sortable="true">Site</th>
                    <th data-field="Entry" data-sortable="true" >Income</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </Aux>
    );
 }

export default Table;
```

The idea is to go this route to "embedd" the js file as a Javascript  import in the page. Therefore be able to utilize all the added functionalities that are available for bootstrap-table (which are not present as an NPM extension install).

However the net result is an error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.js:1
```

Where the bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.js file is valid. I have followed this is as one of the 4 suggestions found at: 
[4 Ways to Add External JavaScript Files in React](https://medium.com/better-programming/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I go a different route with: import ScriptTag from 'react-script-tag'; and then <ScriptTag type="text/babel" src="../../../../assets/js/bootstrap-table/fixed-columns/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.js" /> then the error goes away. Just not sure if I am hacking it in this fashion rather than choosing a more professional route.

Comment: consider using dynamic import [code-spliting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import)